# NullPointerException when displaying a list of data on a JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, nullpointerexception, web-development-server

I am facing an issue when trying to display a list of data on a JSP page. My web application is developed using NetBeans IDE, Tomcat server, and MySQL database. I have a method that creates a list filled with data from the "automoveis" table in my database. Then, this list is sent to a JSP page through a servlet.

Here is the code of the method responsible for creating the list:

```
public List<Automoveis> consultarTodosAutomoveis() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Connection con = Conexao.getConexao();
    PreparedStatement comando = con.prepareStatement("select * from automoveis;");
    ResultSet rs = comando.executeQuery();
    List<Automoveis> lauto  = new ArrayList<Automoveis>();
    int cont = 0;
    while(rs.next()) {
        Automoveis auto = new Automoveis();
        auto.setIdAuto(rs.getInt("idAuto"));
        auto.setMarca(rs.getString("marca"));
        auto.setModelo(rs.getString("modelo"));
        auto.setCor(rs.getString("cor"));
        auto.setImportado(rs.getString("importado"));
        auto.setNumeroRodas(rs.getInt("numeroRodas"));
        auto.setPreco(rs.getDouble("preco"));
        lauto.add(auto);
        cont++;
    }
    System.out.println("Cont..: " + cont);
    con.close();
    return lauto;
}
```

In the servlet, I obtain the list by calling this method and assign it as a request attribute to send it to the JSP page:

```
try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
    MetodosDAO mdao = new MetodosDAO();
    try {
        List<Automoveis> lauto = mdao.consultarTodosAutomoveis();
        request.setAttribute("lauto", lauto);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("resultadoconsultartodsautomoveis.jsp").forward(request, response);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The JSP page "resultadoconsultartodsautomoveis.jsp" is responsible for displaying the data from the list:

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="model.Automoveis"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Result of Consulting All Automoveis</h1>
    <%
        List<Automoveis> lauto = (List<Automoveis>) request.getAttribute("lauto");
    %>
    <% for (Automoveis auto : lauto) { %>
        Id: <%= auto.getIdAuto() %><br>
        Brand: <%= auto.getMarca() %><br><br>
        Model: <%= auto.getIdAuto() %><br><br>
        Color: <%= auto.getCor() %><br><br>
        Imported: <%= auto.getImportado() %><br><br>
        Number of Wheels: <%= auto.getNumeroRodas() %><br><br>
        Price: <%= auto.getPreco() %><br><br>
    <% } %>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I execute the "resultadoconsultarautomoveis.jsp" page, I receive the following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message An exception occurred processing [/resultadoconsultartodsautomoveis.jsp] at line [21]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing [/resultadoconsultartodsautomoveis.jsp] at line [21]
...
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.List.iterator()" because "lauto" is null
...
```

It is important to note that if I execute only the servlet, it works correctly.

I would like to understand why I am receiving this error and how can I fix it to properly display the data on the JSP page.

Comment: Interesting error, `lauto` would appear to be, at the least, an empty list; not `null`.

Comment: Can you find the `System.out.println("Cont..: " + cont);` message within the standard-out, as a way to determine the size?

Comment: I suspect there can be an error that you suppress with `catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)`. Re-throw the error after ` System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());`, then you will most likely see the real cause of the problem.

Comment: @Reilas that error is because the list is `null`.  Empty lists can still provide iterators.  I think Andrej's advice is good.  You should always include stack traces, not just the exception message in logging as well, and you're munching the exception from the consumer pov.  I also think it's odd you have this in your servlet: `try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter())` Are you writing to the response?  that might interfere with your jsp generating the response.

Comment: @Taylor, the list is assigned to a new instance though, if you look at the `consultarTodosAutomoveis` method, it should at least return an empty list, not a `null`

Comment: @Taylor, also, what would an empty list be providing to an iterator?

Comment: I think maybe you get an SqlException because of the semi colon in your sql query : "select * from automoveis;". And so, the attribute is never set on the request.

Comment: @Reilas I guess you were referring to the variable in `consultarTodosAutomoveis`?  It was unclear, as the variable in the jsp is also named `lauto` and the exception is `Cannot invoke "java.util.List.iterator()" because "lauto" is null`.  An empty list can still produce an iterator, so the exception wouldn't happen if the list in the jsp were empty rather than `null`.

Comment: @Taylor, my implication is that if the `lauto` attribute was set to `null`, which is generated by the `consultarTodosAutomoveis`, then it would cause the `NullPointerException`, and considering that `consultarTodosAutomoveis` should be producing, at the least, an empty list, it's an interesting error.  I don't see how it would be set to `null` other than `getAttribute` returning a `null`.

Comment: *org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing [/resultadoconsultartodsautomoveis.jsp] at line [21]* Jasper is a reporting API, but it's not in use in your posted code. So there's something inconsistent there...

Comment: The variable you assign as an attribute cannot be null. Even if you call a servlet and it works, then it doesn't work in the JSP because the attribute is not available.